# Solve not giving a solution for given variables

Tags: equation-solving

Solve is not giving me a solution for the following:

```
Solve[(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] (1 + ((2 c)/h - S + X)/
 Sqrt[((2 c)/h - S + X)^2 - (
  0.5888732894400128` (S - 1.` X)^2 (S + X))/Sqrt[S X]]))/(Sqrt[T] (S + X)) == 0, c]
```

I'm trying to figure out if the problem is the expression itself or the way I am telling Mathematica to solve it. (Here S,X,h, c, and T can all be assumed to be positive reals.)

Comment: Works for me in 12.2, producing `{}`, i.e. no solution.

Comment: After edit a supperfluous parent in the numerator. It was (and should be) `Solve[(1 + ((2 c)/h - S + X)/
      Sqrt[((2 c)/h - S + X)^2 - (0.5 (S - 1.X)^2 (S + X))/
         Sqrt[S X]])/(Sqrt[T] (S + X)) == 0, c]` there.

Comment: Replacing `((2 c)/h-S+X)^2->u` and `(0.5(S - X)^2 (S + X))/Sqrt[S X]->k` one comes to equation `u/(u - k) == 1` that has no solution.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: Think of `k==0` for certain values of parameters. Your conclusion is not true. `Reduce` performs `(0 == -1. X - 1. Sqrt[X^2] && h != 0 &&     0 == -((2. (c + Sqrt[c^2/h^2] h))/h) && c T X != 0 &&     S == X) || (0 == X - 1. Sqrt[X^2] && h != 0 &&     0 == -((2. (c + Sqrt[c^2/h^2] h))/h) && c T X != 0 && S == X)` and a warning. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need

Comment: @user64494  It is not my task to think about such things. It is the task of OP. He knows the problem and understands the origin of his parameters, finally, it is he who understands if the solution like "any u" makes any sense. It is not me who knows all this. My task is only and exceptionally to discuss a possible way to go further and to explain to a newbie, what the empty curly braces in Mma mean.